# Simple Jquery function not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing website and now I have to make this work on various browsers. So I have this code.

```
<script>    
var colors = new Array(
                [62, 35, 255], [60, 255, 60], [255, 35, 98], [45, 175, 230], [255, 0, 255], [255, 128, 0]);

            var step = 0;
            //color table indices for: 
            // current color left
            // next color left
            // current color right
            // next color right
            var colorIndices = [0, 1, 2, 3];

            //transition speed
            var gradientSpeed = 0.002;

            function updateGradient() {

                if ($ === undefined) return;

                var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
                var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
                var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
                var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

                var istep = 1 - step;
                var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
                var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
                var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
                var color1 = "rgb(" + r1 + "," + g1 + "," + b1 + ")";

                var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
                var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
                var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
                var color2 = "rgb(" + r2 + "," + g2 + "," + b2 + ")";

                $('#gradient').css({
                    background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(" + color1 + "), to(" + color2 + "))"
                }).css({
                    background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, " + color1 + " 0%, " + color2 + " 100%)"
                });

                step += gradientSpeed;
                if (step >= 1) {
                    step %= 1;
                    colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
                    colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

                    //pick two new target color indices
                    //do not pick the same as the current one
                    colorIndices[1] = (colorIndices[1] + Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
                    colorIndices[3] = (colorIndices[3] + Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

                }
            }

            setInterval(updateGradient, 10);
</script>
<style>
    #gradient {
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
            }
</style>
<body id="gradient" style="height:90vh; opacity:0">
</body>
```

And I do link a jquery min library. Everything work fine in Firefox, chrome, even Microsoft Edge, Safari. Is it that IE just doesn't support jquery or what?

Comment: Checked *console* on IE? any specific error or issue listed there?

Comment: No. nothing there. But weird thing is that it does support the jquery click.

Comment: Is it because I use the webkit? But if so, how can it work on MS Edge?

Comment: it's because you only add webkit gradient and moz gradient, try adding just linear gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: which version of IE you are using? if it is IE8 or below, it will not work

Comment: its for version, ie 9.

Answer (score 0):

@pwan your javascript looks fine. Only problem is the `vh` unit.

Try giving height in px for the `#gradient` div.

Please have a look. http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Answer (score 0):

You have to add *Gradient* support for IE10 and above also in your *javascript* as:

```
$('#gradient').css({
background: "linear-gradient(to right, " + color1 + " 0%, " + color2 + " 100%)"}).css({
background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(" + color1 + "), to(" + color2 + "))" }).css({ background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, " + color1 + " 0%, " + color2 + " 100%)"});
```

For IE *CSS3* rule will be like this for *Gradient*:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(234, 35, 115) 0%, rgb(255, 31, 115) 100%);
```

Here's working [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/bwNWNo?editors=0010) for a better understanding.

As far as browser supports and better explanation you can refer this url

[**CSS3-gradients**](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients)

**Gradient** won't work on below **IE10** for that you have to use *alternatives* like:

```
  /* Fallback (could use .jpg/.png alternatively) */
  background-color: red;

  /* SVG fallback for IE 9 (could be data URI, or could use filter) */
  background-image: url(fallback-gradient.svg);
```

Comment: yes @Pwan *Gradient* wont work on below **IE10**, you have to use alternatives to replicate the *gradient* like `background-image` etc i.e why I have shared the URL in my answer.